# How can I use gstreamer to mux video, without re-encoding?

Tags: video, gstreamer

I am attempting to use gstreamer to demux an h264 video stream, and wrap the video stream using mp4mux. The following example works, but is going through the additional step of re-encoding the existing h264 video as h264. (Note: this is a live stream with no end, after a few seconds kill the process to see the resulting file).

```
gst-launch-1.0 souphttpsrc location=http://170.93.143.144:1935/rtplive/8b00ad8b0064001f0053fa36c4235c0a/playlist.m3u8 ! \
    hlsdemux ! \
    decodebin ! \
    x264enc ! \
    queue2 ! \
    mp4mux fragment-duration=10 ! \
    filesink location=/tmp/video.mp4
```

The following is a modified pipeline that replaces decodebin & x264enc with h264parse (this does not work):

```
gst-launch-1.0 souphttpsrc location=http://170.93.143.144:1935/rtplive/8b00ad8b0064001f0053fa36c4235c0a/playlist.m3u8 ! \
    hlsdemux ! \
    h264parse ! \
    queue2 ! \
    mp4mux fragment-duration=10 ! \
    filesink location=/tmp/video.mp4
```

When running the modified pipeline, I receive the following error:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstHLSDemux:hlsdemux0: GStreamer encountered a general stream error.
Additional debug info:
gsthlsdemux.c(946): _src_chain (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstHLSDemux:hlsdemux0:
stream stopped, reason not-negotiated
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Comment: Please provide a debug log with GST_DEBUG=6 for the problem. Also note that these pipelines will only work if the HLS stream never switches bitrates, mp4mux' fragment-duration property is in milliseconds (not seconds!), and it probably does not do what you intend to do. What's your goal for the created files, what format should they have?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using GST_DEBUG_DUMP_DOT_DIR="folder where the dot files are going to be after the pipeline is ran"

such as: (if you are in linux)

```
GST_DEBUG_DUMP_DOT_DIR=$PWD \
gst-launch-1.0 souphttpsrc location=http://170.93.143.144:1935/rtplive/8b00ad8b0064001f0053fa36c4235c0a/playlist.m3u8 ! \
    hlsdemux ! \
    decodebin ! \
    x264enc ! \
    queue2 ! \
    mp4mux fragment-duration=10 ! \
    filesink location=/tmp/video.mp4
```

and on another folder

```
GST_DEBUG_DUMP_DOT_DIR=$PWD \
gst-launch-1.0 souphttpsrc location=http://170.93.143.144:1935/rtplive/8b00ad8b0064001f0053fa36c4235c0a/playlist.m3u8 ! \
   hlsdemux ! \
   h264parse ! \
   queue2 ! \
   mp4mux fragment-duration=10 ! \
   filesink location=/tmp/video.mp4
```

And compare both files:

For a graphical comparison you can translate the dot files to png with:

```
dot -Tpng "file.dot" -o "file_something.png"
```